# Creating TypeScript definition with NW.js possible?

Tags: typescript, nw.js

I am attempting to build an NW.js application utilizing TypeScript with the Atom-Typescript plugin.  Unfortunately, DefinitelyTyped does not contain a definition for NW.js so I will need to put together my own `.d.ts` declaration file.

In an effort to test a *very* simple use case, I put together a barebones `nw.gui.ts` file like so:

```
declare module nw.gui {
  class Window {
    get();
  }
}
```

What I can't seem to figure out now is the steps I need to take to actually reference the JS files since they appear to be compiled directly into the nw binary.  Would I need to download the relevant binary's source code and include these files in my project so TypeScript can actually locate them?

Please let me know if this is unclear, a bad idea, or if any other information is required.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Typescript only needs to know where the .d.ts file is to compile. However at runtime your application will need to know where the JS file is to run.

The d.ts is to only help it compile, it does nothing at runtime. so rename nw.gui.ts to nw.gui.d.ts so it is a definition file.

Then what i do, if i understand you correctly, is either include the nw.js file in my html file with your script, or load it dynamically using jQuery or javascript. Just be sure not to reference any NW.js calls until it has been loaded.

Comment: Unfortunately the actual JS files which contains all the namespaces for the API is actually compiled into nw.js, this is where I'm running into the issue.